# Recommend a library for testing the 'closedness' of '.stl' geometries?

Tags: c++, python, 3d-modelling

Some clarification is necessary, I am not referring to the [Standard Template Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library). I am referring to the ['.stl file format'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29).

< my eventual goal >
A little background, my end goal is to use the Kinect and 'point cloud' type scanning to create .stl files. These .stl representations will be provided to 3D printing services to create 3D models. I have the point cloud scanning working quite nicely as well as simple export to .stl (as it's really not that difficult)
< / my eventual goal >

In most 3D cad software packages, you are able to export a model to .stl format. The format is really simple to create by hand and I have no issue with that here. My questions stems from the requirement that most 3D printing services ([Ponoko](http://www.ponoko.com), [Shapeways](http://www.shapeways.com/) to name 2) will not be accept your model if it isn't 'closed' (aka each side of the 'triangle' is a side of another triangle) which is to be expected of them in order to create the 3D object.

There are some software packages (such as [Nettfab](http://www.netfabb.com/)) that can 'fix' these problems but using a 3rd party program will not work for me.

Does anyone have any experience or know of a '.stl' library that will be able to do a 'closedness' check? If not, I will be moving forward and creating one... but I do not want to put the time and effort into something that has (probably) already been done and vetted...

I am also open to a python library if one exists.

**EDIT**

Also looking for this library to 'fix' the stl edges... Just doing a closedness test can be done quite easily but fixing it is the issue...

Comment: Do you mean "no 3rd party program" or "no 3rd party program I have to purchase"?  If the latter, http://wiki.makerbot.com/google-sketchup might be of interest.

Comment: I mean no 3rd party program that I have to manually open, import my 'dirty' .stl model, 'fix', and export back to another .stl file. There is a free version of Nettfab (Studio Basic) that doesnt essentially this and more but I am looking to integrate this capability into my program.

Comment: I've found this ruby library that does some sort of .stl manipulation, but nothing that tests for closedness. https://github.com/aarongough/triangular

Comment: Given that you create the mesh yourself, why don't you make it without cracks in the first place? What kind of errors are there in there?

Comment: i create the mesh off of a 3d scan of an object using the kinect. If I were doing this directly in code, yes... I'd be able to make it a solid right away without issue. The data from the kinect doesn't form EXACT edges (it has a certain resolution...) Essentially what I need this library to be able to do is look at edges that are close to other edges and merge them to form an exact edge. Even one point off of an edge will fail the tests that the 3d printing services uses for closedness.

Comment: Again, it is possible to do myself in code, just not looking to re-invent the wheel...

Comment: guess I'm goin to have to re-invent the wheel? Anyone have any tips?

Comment: You might also want to ensure that you deal with closed [2-manifolds](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/02_Basics.pdf),  i.e an edge is shared by exactly two faces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a look at [Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) which by itself is an application, but it is based on the freely available [VCG](http://vcg.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page) library. It contains dozens of algorithms related to your problem description: automatic vs semi-automatic [hole-filling](http://www.ros.org/doc/unstable/api/vcglib/html/classvcg_1_1tri_1_1Hole.html), [boundary edge](http://vcg.sourceforge.net/index.php/Tutorial#Boundary_relations_and_adjacency) detection and [input/output](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/meshlab/html/classvcg_1_1tri_1_1io_1_1ImporterSTL.html) for the STL ASCII and binary format.

Hope this helps,
Christoph